# Extracting pedestrian step duration from video

Tags: deep-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a front view pedestrian surveillance video of about 15 seconds. The video looks a bit like the picture bellow. I want to estimate the number of frames needed by a pedestrian to complete one step.

Are there any papers available describing techniques that would perform that?

[image: frontal view detected pedestrian]